# SQL Server subquery for manager-employee relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the sample data below. How could I get a list of employee ids by project excluding the employees' managers? I've tried many versions of sub-queries and can remove all managers (employees with no direct reports) but that's not right.

```
emp_id  project_num 
-----   --------
e1      1
e2      1
e3      1
e5      4
e6      4
e7      4
```

Employee table:

```
emp_id  mgr_id
------  ------
e1      e3
e2      e9
e3      e8 (mgr of e1 also on proj 1)
e5      e4
e6      e0 (mgr of e7 also on proj 4)
e7      e6
```

Result example:

```
1 | e1
1 | e2
4 | e5
4 | e7
```

Project 1 excludes e3 and project 4 excludes e6 because they are managers of employees on those same projects.

Comment: Do you also need to remove a manager's manager, a manager's manager's manager, etc? For example, suppose there was a row `{emp_id = e9, project_num = 1}`, and a row `{emp_id = e8, mgr_id = e9}`. So e9 is the manager of e8, and e8 is the manager of e3, and e3 is on project 1. so e9 is transitively a manager of an employee on project 1. Should e9 be excluded from the results for project 1?

Comment: @allmhuran that's an excellent question, but no. It will be highly unlikely to have all three levels on one project. If it does happen, it won't cause any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table projects
(
    emp_id char(3),
    project_num int
)
create table emp
(
    emp_id char(3),
    mgr_id char(3)
)

insert into projects
values
    ('e1', 1),
    ('e2', 1),
    ('e3', 1),
    ('e5', 4),
    ('e6', 4),
    ('e7', 4),
    ('e10', 5),
    ('e3', 5)

insert into emp
values
    ('e1', 'e3'),
    ('e2', 'e9'),
    ('e3', 'e8'),
    ('e5', 'e4'),
    ('e6', 'e0'),
    ('e7', 'e6'),
    ('e10', 'e11')  
  

select project_num, emp_id
from projects p
where p.emp_id not in (
 select mgr_id
from projects p1
    join emp e on e.emp_id = p1.emp_id
where p1.project_num = p.project_num
)

/*
Output
1   e1 
1   e2     
4   e5 
4   e7 
5   e10
5   e3 
*/
```

I added a couple of more entries so ..

- e3 excluded in project 1 since its manager to e1
- e3 would be displayed in project 5 since its manager to no one in project 5

Comment: Thank you. Using the projects table p and then again as p1 was my missing piece.